# Why Latin in Anno Hegirae?

Tags: history, arabic

I just discovered the term "Anno Hegirae" for the first time (I'm not Muslim).

I'm curious, why does the term use Latin rather than Arabic?  Is there a version of the term in Arabic? What is that term (in Arabic and transcribed into English).

Comment: This should probably have an "Islamic Calendar" tag that I don't have sufficient privileges to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper Arabic term is من الهجرة (*min al hijra*), which literally translates as "from the time of the Hijra". So right now it's **1435 من الهجرة**, usually shortened to **1435 هـ**.

However, in English the term 1435 **AH** is usually used, which is (as you have discovered) short for **anno hegirae**. This is a modern usage that deliberately corresponds to the usage of **AD** (anno dominee) for the Gregorian calendar. I have no information on when this usage was adopted.

Comment: According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anno%20hegirae), it's first known use was in 1613.